# How do you hit a SignalR ServerlessHub method?

Tags: websocket, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr, signalr-service

I'm trying to move my app using SignalR from a "traditional server based" to an Serverless Azure Function App.  I have no problem hitting the Negotiate method, but my most basic client-to-server method will not fire.

```cs
// Server endpoints...
namespace TooDuh.Serverless.Hubs
{
  public class TestHub: ServerlessHub
  {
        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req )
        {
            var claims = GetClaims(req.Headers["Authorization"]);
            var connectionInfo = Negotiate( req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"], claims );

            return connectionInfo;
        }

        [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
        public async Task SendMessage(
            [SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string message, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Receive {message} from {invocationContext.ConnectionId}.");

            char[] stringArray = message.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(stringArray);
            string reversedStr = new string(stringArray);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", reversedStr);

        }
...
```

```
// Client method...
async function sendToServer(){
  try {
    console.log("[Client.SignalR.SendMessage] " + userInput.value);
    await connection.invoke("SendMessage", userInput.value);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Is there something different I'm supposed to do with the bindings?  The docs are a real scramble, but I'm trying to work from AzureSignalR-samples/[BidirectionChat](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/BidirectionChat) on GitHub... which does nothing better when I try to debug locally.

Comment: Can you share how you call that Negotiate function/how you connect to the hub? Keep in mind that you can't test SignalRTrigger functions locally without an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i am able to hit a SignalR ServerlessHub method

**Step-1:** Create an Azure Functions project

**Step-2:** Make sure your Azure Functions project is configured properly to use SignalR. The SignalR service connection string should be stored in your configuration.
In the `local.settings.json` file for local development

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "YOUR_SIGNALR_CONNECTION_STRING"
  }
}
```

**Step-3:** Create Your SignalR Hub

```cs
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;
    
    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(SignalRFunctionApp.Startup))]
    
    namespace SignalRFunctionApp
    {
        public class TestHub : ServerlessHub
        {
            [FunctionName("negotiate")]
            public SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req)
            {
                var connectionInfo = Negotiate(req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"]);
                return connectionInfo;
            }
    
            [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
            public async Task SendMessage(
                [SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, string message, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Received message: {message} from {invocationContext.ConnectionId}");
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step-4:** Add Required Packages

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Step-5:** Client Code
You can use a simple HTML/JavaScript client to connect to your SignalR hub.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Client</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.9/signalr.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <button onclick="sendToServer()">Send Message</button>

    <script>
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/api/negotiate")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
            console.log("Received message from server: " + message);
        });

        async function sendToServer() {
            const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
            try {
                // Check if the connection is in the "Connected" state
                if (connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Connected) {
                    console.log("[Client.SignalR.SendMessage] " + userInput.value);
                    await connection.invoke("SendMessage", userInput.value);
                } else {
                    console.error("Connection is not in the 'Connected' state.");
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }

        connection.start()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Connected to the SignalR hub");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(`Error connecting to the hub: ${error}`);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Verify the Connection State**:

Before invoking the "SendMessage" method, ensure that the SignalR connection is in the "Connected" state. You can use the `state` property of the connection to check the current state and ensure it's connected before sending a message

**Result**
[image]